# Реализация поверхности тора в игре Конвея "Жизнь"

Tags: java

Класс в котором мы читаем текстовый файл с матрицей и количеством поколений:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextFileReader {
private char[][] cells;
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;
private int generation;

public void readFromFile(){

    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\life\\test.txt")))
        {
            String value;
            while ((value = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (width == 0) {
                    width = value.length();
                }
                height++;
            }
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

            cells = new char[height-1][width];

    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\life\\test.txt")))
        {
            String currentLine;
            int row = 0;

            while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();

                if (row < (height-1)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                        cells[row][i] = currentLine.charAt(i);
                    }
                } else {
                    generation = Integer.parseInt(currentLine);
                }

                row++;
            }
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //========================= For Testing ===========================//
    System.out.println("Ширина: " + width + " Высота: " + (height-1));
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
             System.out.print(cells[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Количество поколений: " + generation);
}

public char[][] getCells() {
    return cells;
}

public char getCell(int row, int col) {
    return cells[row][col];
}

public void setCells(char[][] cells) {
    this.cells = cells;
}

public int getGeneration() {
    return generation;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height-1;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
}
```

Класс, в котором выполняется вся логика:

```
public class Cell {
TextFileReader textFileReader = new TextFileReader();
private char[][] temporalCell;

public void action () {
    textFileReader.readFromFile();
    temporalCell = new char[textFileReader.getHeight()][textFileReader.getWidth()];

    for (int i = 1; i < textFileReader.getGeneration(); i++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < textFileReader.getHeight(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < textFileReader.getWidth(); col++) {
                int currentNeighbours = neighbours(row, col);

                if (currentNeighbours > 3 || currentNeighbours < 2) {
                    temporalCell[row][col] = '.';
                } else if (currentNeighbours == 3) {
                    temporalCell[row][col] = 'o';
                } else {
                   temporalCell[row][col] = textFileReader.getCell(row, col);
                }
            }
        }
        textFileReader.setCells(temporalCell);
    }
}

public int neighbours (int row, int col) {
    int neighboursCount = 0;
    for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
            if (textFileReader.getCell(i, j) == ('o') && (i != row || j != col)) {
                neighboursCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return neighboursCount;
}
}
```

Программа выкидывает Exception в методе neighbours(), что есть логично, т.к. мы выходим за границы матрицы, потому что у нас нет метода, определяющего границы поля. Но суть не в этом. Как мне реализовать поверхность тора, что бы левая граница соединялась с правой, а верхняя - с нижней? Пересмотрел много примеров, но понять, как это реализовать, так и не смог((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте не сами координаты, а остаток от деления их на размеры поля. То есть, при проходе по соседним клеткам определяйте их координаты как `textFileReader.getCell(i % textFileReader.getHeight(), j % textFileReader.getWidth())`. Таким образом, координаты никогда не превысят размеры матрицы, а если превысят, то от них автоматически отнимется высота (ширина) матрицы, и они перейдут на её пртоивоположную сторону.

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что остаток от деления отрицательного числа на положительное с помощью % выдает отрицательный остаток, о чём следует позаботиться.

Comment: fori1ton, спасибо большое, суть понял)
AlexeyM, я вот как раз над этим мозгую, в гугловском калькуляторе:     (-1) % 4 = 3,
а в Java = -1.

Но если к делимому прибавить делитель, то всё вроде бы получается:
(-1+4)%4=3